# How to check for corresponding words in a string to a CSV file?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

```
CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').build();
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader).withCSVParser(parser).withSkipLines(1).build();
List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();

String studentName = "Alice, Bob";
String[] words = studentName.split(",");

List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

for(String[]row:allData){ // goes through the csv file
        for(String word:words){ // goes through String names
        if(row[3].contains(word)){
        names.add(row[4]);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the for-loop only goes through the CSV file to check for "Alice", and doesn't check "Bob", and therefore Bob does not get added to the list, how would I solve that?

row[3] = names

row[4] = school

@xerx593 spotted the mistake, this sovled it:

```
String[] words = studentName.split(", ");
```

Comment: Is it possibly a simple mistake? `"Alice, Bob".split(",")` splits to `{"Alice", " Bob"}` (Bob with a blank in front (`" "`)? ;(

Comment: If that is the (only) issue, You can: `split(", ")` and/or `word.trim()`

Comment: @xerx593 Well spotted! I've trying to solve this issue for a while now, thanks! Added your comment to the question with your solution.

Comment: When you have a solution, rather post it as answer! ;) (But these types of q/a (here) are normally quickly closed due to "simple mistake/typo/not reproducible) Anyways, very welcome & merry X-Mas! :-)

Comment: @xerx593 Have done that now. Merry Christmas to you too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a spelling error.

@xerx593 spotted the mistake, this sovled it:

```
String[] words = studentName.split(", ");
```